# CoreBluetooth : Why DidDiscover delegate method is not always being called?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, obd-ii, dongle

when it's called i have this log [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP1be.png)

PS : i am working with an OBD2 dongle as a peripheral and my iphone is the centralManager

Answer (score 0):

When scanning using CoreBluetooth on iOS you have the option to set the [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerscanoptionallowduplicateskey) flag to True if you want to receive the callback for every advertisement event that the manager receives. Please note, though, that the manager is not guaranteed to actually receive all the packets that the peripheral transmits.